# How can i order this list using paired father-son with php?

Tags: php, arrays, list, tree

Im writing a selectbox where the data from a hierarchical id-parent database. The data is like:
id - parent_id

```
126 - 120
114 - 108
105 - 52
140 - 116
142 - 116
145 - 116
122 - 120
116 - 3
118 - 116
125 - 120
102 - 3
123 - 120
120 - 3
130 - 116
119 - 116
128 - 120
141 - 116
117 - 116
121 - 120
104 - 2
```

I need organize this in something like:

```
array(
    3 => array(
        102 => array(
                    122, 123, 125
               )
        )
        116...
        120...
    )
)
```

Code so far

```
foreach($rsCat->linha() as $cat){ 
    append($cat, $list); 
} 
function append($cat, &$list){ 
    if( array_key_exists($cat->subcat, $list) ){ 
        $this->pendura($cat, $list[$cat->subcat]); 
    }
    else  { 
        $list[$cat->subcat][] = $cat->cat_id; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you made any effort in solving this so far?

Comment: I try, but so far..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use recursive function/method:

```
function recursiveGroup($level, $grouped) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($grouped[$level] as $item) {
        $result[$item] = recursiveGroup($item, $grouped);
    }

    return $result;
}

$array = [126 => 120, 114 => 108, ...];

$grouped = [];
foreach ($array as $child => $parent) {
    if (!array_key_exists($parent, $grouped)) {
        $grouped[$parent] = [];
    }

    $grouped[$parent][] = $child;
}

// Here we find minimal id for the beginning of our grouped array
$minId = min(array_keys($grouped));

$result[$minId] = recursiveGroup($minId, $grouped);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using recursion, but this does re-order the items to be in order...

```
$input = [[126, 120],
    [114, 108],
    [105, 52],
    [140, 116],
    [142, 116],
    [145, 116],
    [122, 120],
    [116, 3],
    [118, 116],
    [125, 120],
    [102, 3],
    [123, 120],
    [120, 3],
    [130, 116],
    [119, 116],
    [128, 120],
    [141, 116],
    [117, 116],
    [121, 120],
    [104, 2]];

// Sort the input
rsort($input);
$output = [];
foreach ( $input as $pair ) {
    // pair[0] is the child ID, pair[1] is the parent ID
    // Check if existing item should be promoted to it's new parent ID
    if ( isset($output[$pair[0]]) ) {
        $output[$pair[1]][$pair[0]] = $output[$pair[0]];
        // Remove the old item
        unset($output[$pair[0]]);
    }
    else {
        // Add new child item to parent
        $output[$pair[1]][] = $pair[0];
    }
}
print_r($output);
```